# Why do I get an HRESULT 0x800A03EC when using Worksheets.Visible?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, worksheet

I've been trying to figure out ways to tell the difference between instances of excel that load the worksheets and ones that don't

Currently I use code to open existing files that looks something like that:

```
Dim wkbWorkBook as Excel.Workbook
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application

wkbWorkBook = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(filename) 
objExcel = wkbWorkBook.Parent

'To make the excel app visible while working with it: 
objExcel.Visible  = true
```

What i've noticed while using this code is that If I open a file that exists, but isn't open in excel, when I make the Excel Application visible, the Worksheets aren't visible, but they do exist (I can access worksheets.count and there is an appropriate number of sheets)

I try using Worksheets.Visible but I've noticed it only has an HRESULT error in the place where a "Visible" value would be.    [image: In code Error shows up in Worksheets properties]

The same error occurs when I try to get the Visible property even when the worksheets are visible (in cases when I BindToMoniker() a file that is currently open in excel..  )

Part of my question is why the BindToMoniker() + Application = workbook.Parent is always giving me an Excel Application without any sheets loaded..  I can't work with it when it's like that..

Comment: HRESULT: 0x800A03EC is an unknown (to VB.Net) COM error. This usually happens when Excel throws some error because your input or parameters were wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without gurantees, but I would say worksheets.visible -> won't work, becasue worksheets gives you a list of worksheets.

You cannot apply .visible on that -> you would have to use worksheets(1).visible

Additionally, if there aren't any worksheets, this should fail anyways. you would have to check your count of worksheets first.

Another thing - i don't know if this is possible under vb.net with interop, but maybe you can access specific worksheets through their internal codename - like this:

```
pobjExcel.table1.visible
```